# Number of Processors and Computer Speed relation?

Tags: windows-7, windows, speed, dell-xps, intel-core-i5

Does changing the number of processors under **Boot Advanced Options** affect computer speed?

[image: 1]

I have Dell XPS 15z Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit) OS with 4GB RAM, intel i5 processor @2.5 Ghz and 1GB nVidia Graphics.By default, it uses 4 cpu however my system is slow in booting up and seems lazy doing simple things like opening programs and files, i mean the response is slow.

However, when I reduced the number of process to 2 or 3 or 1, the boot up time reduced significantly and system responded quick to any actions but there was lag as it was clear with gaming.

I don't know what to do.....it's so embarassing to have high performance gaming computer but still sucks at doing normal operations especially booting up - it takes more than 4 minutes!

I have very few programs to run at start up.

Any suggestions to improve the speed of my system?

Comment: Is it a clean install or riddled with OEM apps? Can you check Task Manager to watch which app take over a core (25% on CPU usage)?

Comment: Is there a difference between the time it takes with multiple or one CPU till the first "lifesign" of Windows (Bootscreen) shows up? If there is a difference, then it is probably a hardware issue (or BIOS issue).

Comment: Ok... I was to slow with my comment. You updated you question in the meantime. I there a difference if you start Windows in the safe-mode (I have just a german windows and I am not sure about the translation) and the normal startup? I mean: I a difference between the multiple cpu and one in the safe mode?

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo There are pre installed Dell apps like dell datasafe, dell camera, but i have configured not to run those apps during start up.Also when 4 processors are used, the cpu reading just aroud 10%

Comment: @ChaosCakeCoder No, but time difference is only between the login screen and when the desktop shows up.I tried booting in safe mode, it's pretty fast.

Comment: Then I would first try to disable all autostarted apps (you can use http://technet.microsoft.com/de-ch/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx or run msconfig with Win+R). Maybe it is also an installed service.

Comment: Install the `Windows Performance Toolkit` and run xbootmgr and make a boot trace when you use the default setting and when you have limited the CPU to other values.


http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/140247-trace-windows-7-bootshutdownhibernatestandbyresume-issues/

Comment: Does your CPU support hyperthreading? If so, 12.5% would indicate a process is hogging the CPU. Change your Processor graph to Logical Processors, or just open the Process tabs and watch which process takes 12.5%

Answer (score 4):

The processor is one component of a PC that affects speed, but there are ***many*** factors that contribute to a slow computer.

If you notice speed problems on boot, and opening folders, programs and other files, more than likely it's not your processor that is the culprit, but your hard drive and RAM. *Buy an **SSD** and make sure you have at least **4 GB*** (preferably 8 if you're gaming) of the fastest memory your board can support. *Perform a **clean install*** of your O/S* from a non-OEM disc (crapware is crapware). *Install the **latest drivers for your devices*.

*Disable services that you don't need, as well as any startup programs that can be manually launched when needed.*

To answer your original question, **yes**, *crippling a processor by only using one of its cores will slow down your computer*. Would only using one cylinder in your engine make it go slower?

Comment: And just a side note, taking the time to uninstall this and that might speed up your PC by 0.00001%, but in the end the havoc that has been wrought on your registry can't be undone without a clean O/S install. I'm one of those people that says "When in doubt, start fresh. Work smarter, not harder."

Comment: Excellent answer. And solid advice imo.